# c# regular expression pattern matching

Tags: c#, regex

we have a string

```
string strScope = "This site is used for business group. [Title]Business Group[/Title][URL]http://google.com[\URL]";
```

In C# how we will get the Business Group from title & url from the above string.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

A great resource for testing regular expressions is [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com).

```
\[Title\]([^\[]+)\[/Title\]\[URL\]([^\[]+)\[\\URL\]
```

The above will match what you posted.  I assume you meant to use a "/" in URL, which would be matched by

```
\[Title\]([^\[]+)\[/Title\]\[URL\]([^\[]+)\[/URL\]
```

Code example (assuming you actually want the [\URL]

```
        string strScope = "This site is used for business group. [Title]Business Group[/Title][URL]http://google.com[\URL]";

        var match = Regex.Match( strScope, @"\[Title\]([^\[]+)\[/Title\]\[URL\]([^\[]+)\[\\URL\]");
        if ( match.Groups.Count >= 2)
        {
            string name = match.Groups[0].Value;
            string url = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
```

Obviously use the other regex if you want the more conventional [/URL]

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
@"\[Title\]([^\[]+)\[/Title\]\[URL\]([^\[]+)\[/URL\]"
```

The first capturing group will be `"Business Group"`; the second one will contain the URL.

[Here is a quick demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/hTy6V).

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\[Title\]([^\[]+)\[/Title\]\[URL\]([^\[]+)\[/URL\]");
var txt = "This site is used for business group. [Title]Business Group[/Title][URL]http://google.com[/URL]";
var m = rx.Match(txt);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2]);
```

This prints

```
Business Group
http://google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
\[(?<tag>[^\]]+)](?<value>.*?)\[/\k<tag>]
```

Group `tag` matches tag name, in your case: `Title`, `URL`.
Group `value` matches value of this tag.

I assume your input is:

```
[Title]Business Group[/Title][URL]http://google.com[/URL]
```

Result:

[image: Result]

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\[(?<tag>[^\]]+)](?<value>.*?)\[/\k<tag>]");
var txt = "This site is used for business group. [Title]Business Group[/Title [URL]http://google.com[/URL]";
var m = rx.Matches(txt);

foreach (Match match in m)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", match.Groups["tag"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
}
```